# Set value conditionally depending on Helm (first) install or upgrade?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am using `bitnami/mongodb` as a dependency for my helm chart. With this chart autogenerating secrets for e.g. `mongodb.auth.rootPassword` on install, I want to use the existing secret upon updating the chart, instead of the "empty value" which causes auto generation.

To be clear: The above is just an example / my usecase, the following question is a general question regarding Helm.

Is there any variable in helm to check wether it is an install or an update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of using a third-party chart, the only thing you can really do is to create the password outside of Helm and inject it (using a `-f my-values.yaml` file or the `--set` option).  The [Bitnami MySQL chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mysql) has a more specific note on [upgrading](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mysql#upgrading):

> It's necessary to set the `root.password` parameter when upgrading for readiness/liveness probes to work properly. When you install this chart for the first time, some notes will be displayed providing the credentials you must use under the 'Administrator credentials' section. Please note down the password and run the command below to upgrade your chart:
>
> ```
> $ helm upgrade my-release bitnami/mysql --set root.password=[ROOT_PASSWORD]
> ```

If you controlled the template, in principle you can check [`.Release.IsUpgrade`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/) but it won't actually help you here.  If you had template code like

```
{{- if not .Release.IsUpgrade -}}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
...
{{- end -}}
```

what it would actually do, on upgrade, is notice that the set of Kubernetes manifests doesn't include the Secret object any more, and delete it.

I'd avoid using the Sprig functions to randomly generate a password, or chart-level options to generate one, specifically because Helm doesn't have any way to remember the password and it will get overwritten on every upgrade.

Comment: You can also do `{{- if .Release.IsInstall -}}` instead of `{{- if not .Release.IsUpgrade -}}` for cleaner code

Answer (score -1):

You can pass existing password to args when install helm chart

```
helm install mongodb bitnami/mongodb --set auth.rootPassword='passwords'
```

Comment: That does not answer my question at all. As I am deploying my release through gitlab auto-deploy and want passwords to be autogenerated, this is not an option.

Comment: this is general helm installation thing , you can pass args value with help of --set . btw you didn't mention gitlab auto-deploy things in question .

Comment: use the HELM_UPGRADE_EXTRA_ARGS environment variable to override the default chart values by setting HELM_UPGRADE_EXTRA_ARGS to --values <my-values.yaml>

Comment: follow this link to understand how you can pass helm args :- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/customize.html#customize-values-for-helm-chart

Comment: This is just an example. I don't want to pass any variables by hand, I want to determine if the deployment is using a previously generated secret which exists after first install. Nothing to do with gitlab nor the chart I am using, just a general Helm question.