# Helm chart prevent value from being changed

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a Helm chart where a certain value is set when a release is installed and changing it would break the underlying software.

There are many cases when someone could accidentally change it and if the change gets applied - it's game over - several hours of recovery from backups.

I would like to implement a check on upgrade that fails the upgrade if said value is changed.

I considered using the `lookup` function, but my experiments showed unreliable and inconsistent results. Another one would be a `pre-upgrade` hook that would evaluate the change and prevent the rest of the chart from running.

But these seem like hacks. I was wondering if there is a more Helm way to define, basically a constant value that should be preserved throughout a release.

Answer (score 0):

Helm values might not be what you are looking for if you want to "hardcode" values.

If you accept multiple "allowed" values for your input variable, you can force these values in your [schema files](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#schema-files), e.g:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "image": {
      "description": "Container Image",
      "properties": {
        "version": {
          "type": "string"
          "oneOf": ["thatVersion"]
        },
```

Or, you can create a file name [`_variables.tpl`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/) for example, and

```
{{- define "img_version" -}}
  {{- print "thatVersion" -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Then you use it as a template with [`include`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/#the-include-function):

```
thatKey:  {{ include "img_version" . }}
```

Or the last solution would be bending the best-practice rule of "not using hardcoded values" and just hard-code that value in your templates and not exposing it via `values.yaml`.

See more:

- https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#schema-files
- https://cswr.github.io/JsonSchema/spec/basic_types/
- https://cswr.github.io/JsonSchema/spec/generic_keywords/

Comment: I wonder if I'm doing something wrong, but I made a few tests with "readOnly" and it seems not working. My idea is, that a certain value can only be configured once when helm install is called, but not when using helm upgrade. Has anyone tried the same?

Comment: @newduino comments are not the right place to ask unrelated questions. Anyways, you might be looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64062475/set-value-conditionally-depending-on-helm-first-install-or-upgrade